# Linux Command for a Raw DNS Response

Tags: linux, dns, command, nslookup

Does anyone know how to fetch the raw output of a DNS query using a particular linux command?

The commands that I am familiar with are:

% host

% nslookup

% dig

% whois

however, each of these play around with DNS in some form or another, but how can I get the raw output that the server DNS spits out when its queried?

Many Thanks!

Comment: whois is actually a different protocol altogether from DNS.

Comment: tcpdump is the quickest solution as noted by jcomeau_ictx.  Run it while using the 'host' ccommand to capture what is going back and forth.  Otherwise, you will need to write your DNS client.  BTW, have you tried the -v option to 'host'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that the best solution to find out as much of the DNS stuff as possible is to use the `host -v` command.

```
host -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

or

```
host -v domain.com
```

Answer (score 5):

you could get it with tcpdump while running dig. I believe the flags would be `tcpdump -n -s0 -x -X port 53`

Comment: if you want to watch DNS over TLS aswell, you want to have a look at port 853

Comment: @WorldSEnder and being TLS the network dump will show just garbage, that is encrypted data, and not the DNS packet anymore (which is the first purpose of DoT)